# Golang ICMP Packet Sending

Tags: go, network-programming, wireshark, icmp

I am currently working on a Go based router for educational purposes.

When attempting to serialize an ICMP packet that I am forwarding from a host it appears that the .SerializeTo function of the gopacket.ICMPv4 struct is stripping the ICMP payload portion and only including type, code, checksum, id, and sequence in the byte array it returns to the buffer.

Below is the code I am using to send my eth, ip, and icmp layer out my WAN interface. The only things that I have changed about these layers after I received them from my LAN interface is ICMP ID, Ethernet src/dst, and IP src.

```
opts := gopacket.SerializeOptions{FixLengths: true, ComputeChecksums: true}
buff := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
_ = gopacket.SerializeLayers(buff, opts, ethLayer, ipLayer, icmpLayer)
```

The ICMP layer before I send it showing that it has a payload portion:

icmpLayer = &{BaseLayer:{Contents:[8 0 65 238 7 109 0 1] Payload:[122 238 50 94 15 84 7 0 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55]} TypeCode:EchoRequest Checksum:53486 Id:10000 Seq:1}

PCAP LAN side of the client sending the ICMP request to the server.
[image: PCAP host to server]

PCAP WAN side of the server forwarding request to destination. 
[image: PCAP server to WAN]

If there is any additional information requested please let me know, I attempted to provide as much context as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up identifying that the ICMP class SerializeTo func was stripping out payload when it put its byte array representation into the buffer. For testing I was able to change the function to use the following code to dynamically allocate more space if the packet has a payload portion, then add the payload into buffer. Will be posting this as a bug on the git to either get resolved or point out why this use case is an edge case.

```
// SerializeTo writes the serialized form of this layer into the
// SerializationBuffer, implementing gopacket.SerializableLayer.
// See the docs for gopacket.SerializableLayer for more info.
func (i *ICMPv4) SerializeTo(b gopacket.SerializeBuffer, opts gopacket.SerializeOptions) error {
    bytes, err := b.PrependBytes(len(i.Payload)+8)//8)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    i.TypeCode.SerializeTo(bytes)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(bytes[4:], i.Id)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(bytes[6:], i.Seq)

    startIndex := 8
    for _, element := range i.Payload {
        bytes[startIndex] = byte(uint16(element))
        startIndex+= 1
    }

    if opts.ComputeChecksums {
        bytes[2] = 0
        bytes[3] = 0
        i.Checksum = tcpipChecksum(b.Bytes(), 0)
    }
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(bytes[2:], i.Checksum)

    return nil
}
```